# 'Create a Record' Action Navigation

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, administration, action

**Scenario:** I currently have an Action associated with the Account object that creates a new Opportunity, with fields mapped to that new Opportunity, from the Account where the user clicks the Action.  I am attempting to replicate an existing business process that uses a URL hack embedded in a JavaScript button in classic.  The action does everything that I need it too, except for navigating to the newly created Opportunity.

**Question:** Is there a method using Flows, Process Builder, or some other means, to make a 'Create a Record' Action automatically navigate to the newly created record, without the user needing to click a link in the related list, after the Action runs?

**Note:** I am trying to do this without writing any code, using only Administration.